# Problem with Springer Nature bibliography style （citation style: numbered, sort in alphabetical order）

Tags: bibliographies

I am preparing my first paper. The format required by the Journal is that reference citations in the text should be identified by numbers in square brackets and the reference list at the end of the document Must be placed in alphabetical order. But in the Springer Nature LaTeX template 2021, there is no bibstyle satisfy this. The 'sn-basic, sn-apa, sn-chicago, sn-standardnature' has 'alphabetical order' but the citation style of them are 'authoryear'. The 'sn-mathphys, sn-aps, sn-vancouver, sn-standardnature' has the style 'numbered' but is 'accuarance order'.
How to modify these templates to meet the requirements of journals？ 'numbered' and 'alphabetical order' I am using sn-mathphys and I want the references numbered and in alphabetical order.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked the biblatex manual for a built in style? There should be one that fits that requirements or is trivial to modify the in text citation brackets, the biblatex manual is on ctan.org, sorry I would link to it directly but I'm on my phone

Comment: The Springer Nature LaTeX template that I found uses `natbib` for citations/bibliography and not `biblatex`, so I have changed the tags to more accurately reflect your situation. It is odd that a Springer journal should require a bibliography style that is not supported by the template. Have you tried contacting the editor about this?

Comment: When I download [Springer's journal article template package](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940), I have a `.tex` document which generates references in the style you ask for and not in an authoryear style. I suggest you read the class documentation and the recommendations for your specific journal to find out what to use.